# How do I manipulate gain on a wav file?

Tags: c#, .net, wav

I have a wav file, and I want to play around with the gain on the sound clip (boost in softer areas, reduce at others. And I need to do this to 1k+ files) and save it back to disk.

.NET doesn't seem to have a sound library, and none of the audio libraries I can find seem to have controls for this (Accord, Naudio, SDL2, SharpDX; though I could just not be seeing what I'm looking for). I've also looked into the WAV format to try and do it directly to the byte stream, but I can't find anything more specific than the data block is left-right pair samples.

So, with access to a .wav file, how can I adjust the loudness on a per sample basis? If possible, I'd also like a solution that would allow me to seamlessly work with other sound file formats as well.

Comment: https://markheath.net/post/normalize-audio-naudio . With NAudio and NAudio LAME wrapper you can convert a lot of audio format. There are also NAudio wrapper for Vorbis, etc. I wrote something similar using NAudio for file conversion in the past.

Comment: If you're not limited to coding, most audio editors have **_batch processing_**, allowing you to apply a set of effects processes, say DR compression then normalisation, to multiple files. Much easier than coding a custom DR compression algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAudio seems to provide what you are looking for

> ISampleProvider
>
> The strength of IWaveProvider is that it can be used to represent
> audio in any format. It can be used for 16,24 or 32 bit PCM audio, and
> even for compressed audio (MP3, G.711 etc). But if you are performing
> any kind of signal processing or analysis on the audio, it is very
> likely that you want the audio to be in 32 bit IEEE floating point
> format. And it can be a pain to try to read floating point values out
> of a byte[] in C#.
>
> So ISampleProvider defines an interface where the samples are all 32
> bit floating point

```
public interface ISampleProvider { 
    WaveFormat WaveFormat { get; } 
    int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int.count); 
}
```

https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/WaveProviders.md#isampleprovider

Create custom SampleProvider that takes an input SampleProvider in your constructor. Use input Sample Provider to get samples, multiply by your gain:
Output sample = gain x input sample

Use WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile feeding customSampleProvider.ToWaveProvider() to the appropriate argument, to output back to wav file.